# Problemas con registros unicos laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Dado que he tenido problemas con el método `plunk()` he tratado de buscar la forma de traducir esta consulta a Eloquent, pero hasta hora no lo he logrado, ¿hay alguna forma distinta?

```
select distinct usuario_ad from usuarios;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consulta debe ocupar el método distinct() aunque también puedes usar el método raw() para escribir el método en sql .

**Con Eloquent Laravel:**

```
$data = User::select("usuario_ad")
            ->distinct()
            ->get();
```

**O con el query builder**

```
$data = \DB::table("usuarios")
           ->select("usuario_ad")
           ->distinct()
           ->get();
```

Comment: gracias shadow, claramente entendido